# Delete datagridview selected Row C#

Tags: c#, winforms

i am deleting selected row from my datagridview, below code perform its function, the problem is the codes deleted 2 rows everytime delete keyboard button hit, what is the problem?

```
private void dataGridView2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Delete)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView2.SelectedRows)
            {
                if (dataGridView2.Rows.Count > 1)
                {
                    dataGridView2.Rows.Remove(row);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you debug this, you see the execution step through the loop twice?

Comment: `dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);`

Comment: @JQSOFT, tried already line of code you provided same problem, still deleting 2 rows,

Comment: If you are adding the rows manually like: `dataGridView2.Rows.Add(..)` then to remove the selected rows just do: `if (e.KeyData == Keys.Delete) dataGridView2.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => !r.IsNewRow).ToList().ForEach(r => dataGridView2.Rows.Remove(r));`. If you populate the DGV through the DataSource property then you should remove the entries from the the data source. Clear?

Comment: @JQSOFT thank you.. your code works perfect

Comment: @user10216583 I am adding rows uwing dgv.Rows.Add() but still your suggested code is deleting two rows. Can't understand why it's happening so?

Comment: Observation: the malfunction (deletion of two rows when one is selected) happens when KeyDown event (detecting Keys.Delete) of DataGridView is programmed. When the same code is put in the Clicked event of a button, it works perfectly fine. Strange...